# What is Lie-dragging? What is the relationship between Lie-dragging and Lie-derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation

[image: lie-dragging] 
I found lie-dragging at following picture, i can not understand why L and N have property of (12)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the physical meaning of Lie dragging?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275705/)

Comment: @A.V.S.  this is asking about a specific formula